# How to get written text from one text box to other using javascript?

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have two text boxes of name in a table. I want; as the user types a name in first text box it should also be appeared in the other on the same time as well. Please guide me. It's a home assignment and I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind  a `input` event handler to `first` textbox.

```js
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener("input",Input,false);
function Input(){
    document.getElementById('second').value=this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first">
<input type="text" id="second">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. We copy the text from and to when the user is typing.

```
<textarea id="from" onkeyup="copy_text()"></textarea>
<textarea id="to"></textarea>
<script>
function copy_text() {
document.getElementById("to").value = document.getElementById("from").value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is not working properly because the event should be listened after the key is released. You can use jQuery to have this solved (is not mandatory). I hope it helps.

```
boxone: <input type="text" id="boxone">
boxtwo: <input type="text" id="boxtwo">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "#boxone" ).keyup(function() {

   $("#boxtwo").val($("#boxone").val());
});
</script>
```